# Set TreehouseGO app to use the memory card for downloads?

Tags: applications, settings, external-sd

I installed the TreehouseGo app on my wife's Galaxy S4 phone so that she can entertain our daughter while she goes on a trip with her. However, when I tried to download some episodes, I found that there is only 9 MB available to it and that it won't download anything as a result.

So, I went out and got a 64 GB mini SD card, but the app didn't see the new storage. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app, but it still only sees the internal memory.

How do I get the app to see the SD card so that I can download some of the videos? I can't seem to find any settings for that in either the app or the App Manager settings for the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in touch with the help desk for the TreehouseGo app, and they told me that it's not even an option to let the app use the SD card; although they did say that it was a great suggestion and that they would consider implementing it.